# New iMac - New Rails Environment - Dropbox - Permission Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, dropbox

Ok, I just bought the new 27 inch iMac and I am trying get everything set up. I am new to rails and have been developing on my MacBook Pro and seem to be having some trouble sharing my applications. I use dropbox which allowed me to easily access the new files from my new iMac and therefore my rails applications but after installing rails, when I try to start the server for my app, I get:

-bash: script/server: Permission denied.

I am assuming this has to do with the app being protected but not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not protected, I guess you lost the execution right while dropping your files.

Just do:

```
chmod +x script/server
```

You might consider something else for the transfer, like rsync instead of drop box.

Comment: Thanks...not sure I know what you mean though. I basically did these four steps on my new machine:

 sudo gem update --system
 sudo gem install rails
 sudo gem update rake
 sudo gem update sqlite3-ruby

Comment: Hey man...disregard comments...just redid everything and somehow it worked. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sharing the entire application directory structure, I've found that the better solution is to share a git repo via dropbox and then clone it on each machine (I also have an iMac and MBP that I work on)

The problem with storing the app on Dropbox is that the logfiles and possibly sqlite database can chew up a lot of room. Nopt to mention that it's always good to use some sort of SCM (git being the most favored in the Rails community, but others should work fine too.)

I went through the steps to do this on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504721/ruby-on-rails-newbie/1471491#1471491) to another question.